# How to display the selected attribute option in Filtered results page in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, price, layered-navigation, filter

I have displayed the Layered Navigation for my site ,when i choose the price filter it is showing the results within the range i have selected but the price filter option is not displayed in the filtered results page.

How to display the selected filter option in Filtered results page.

Please Suggest!.

Comment: Works here http://demo.magentocommerce.com/bed-and-bath?price=-1000. Looks like you don't have it due to some customisations.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find Shop by Price option in the above url Will you?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the manage attributes and check the properties of `price`. If the use in layered navigation value in `No` then Set the property `use in layered navigation` to `Filterable(with results)`

Answer (score 1):

If the `price` attribute is appearing, your attribute settings are correct.

#### Troubleshooting steps:

1. Determine if there were modifications made in `catalog/layer/view.phtml`.You should see this line: `<?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>`. Worst case, delete the file (if it exists in your custom theme), and see if the problem is resolved.
2. Step through `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php->_prepareLayout()` to ensure that the `$stateBlock` variable is set.
3. Check `catalog/layer/state.phtml`. Are any `$_filters` set?

Comment: Hi SwiftOtter Studios,Yes the $_filters is set in the above mentioned file but the price filter is not displaying in the results page rather it shows the current choosen price